# Deciding on Idempotency Approach on Distirbuted Systems (At Kafka Consumer)

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, apache-kafka

The service that is built works on requests reply method using Kafka consumers. This service communicates with external systems .

1. Whenever an external system requests a message(via KAfka) They had to send the client_id and an idempotent key. 
   2.The service would be saving this unique combination of client_id and idempotent_key in a request table on the first time
2. Before processing the request the client would be checking if it is already processed
3. If duplicate found the request would be ignored

Any recommendations?

Comment: What is your question? Is this approach is OK or if it can be improved ?

Comment: if it could be improved.